# Ruby on Rails return results in % or blocks of info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a web app on Ruby on rails with more than 20 million records and counting in a Postgres database. I have a page/controller that does some big time operations with this data so the user is waiting for more time that I would like.

Is there any way I can return data in blocks of info? I mean, I imagine the user seeing the first 10 rows and waiting for the next ones with a percentage bar that informs him how much is done (10% data returned for ex.)

I guess that with multiple ajax/json calls this could be done but I'm trying to avoid multiple calls.

More: Are websockets really a choice here?

By the way, I'm using Rails 3.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ActiveController::Streaming`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html) feature.

See also

- http://theflyingdeveloper.com/rails_4_streaming_presentation/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/streaming-with-rails-4/

Comment: Sorry but my app is not ready for rails 4 yet. Any other choices?

Comment: [Streaming is available since Rails 3.1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming), as far as I remember.